# Monitor already used serial port using python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyserial

How to monitor serial port is already used or not? I am using pyserial for my application and isOpen() not working for the script when i run it in Ubuntu.

if (ser.isOpen()):
    ser.write(data_string)
else:
    print("Port already in use")

I never got "Port already in use" . I was trying to execute this script parallel in two different terminals still no else part execution was there.

Comment: Try to open it. One possible failure mode is that it is already in use.

Comment: that failure occurs with an exception in one of the two instances which is not acceptable. my requirement is to block the resource.

Comment: Please, post code sample with isOpen that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: if (ser.isOpen()):
    ser.write(data_string)
else:
    print("Port already in use")